# ListFragment Listview - how to automatically set first listview item to selected state?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a ListFragment with ListView. What I want to do is - when ListFragment is created I want first item of it's listview is to be automatically selected (highlighted). For highlighting listview rows I use my custom list selector. I try to set first item of list to selected state, so list selector could highlight it too. But nothing's working with my code. Maybe someone can help me to solve this task? What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: Here is my ListFragment code:

```
public class ObjectListFragment extends ListFragment {

private DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
private ArrayList<FFObject> ffObjects = new ArrayList<>();
private FFObjectsAdapter ffObjectAdapter;
private ArrayList<FFObject> arrayList;
private FFObject ffObject;
private long objectId;

static interface ObjectListListener{
    void itemClicked(long id);        
}

private ObjectListListener listener;

public ObjectListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.listener = (ObjectListListener) context;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    refreshData();        
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_object_list, null);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);                      
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    listView.setItemChecked(2,true);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);        

    arrayList = this.ffObjects;        
    ffObject = arrayList.get(position);
    long itemId = ffObject.getObjectID();

    Log.d("ObjectListFragment","Clicked on item with id = "+itemId);
    if (listener != null){
        listener.itemClicked(itemId);
    }        
}

public long getObjectId() {

    arrayList = this.ffObjects;
    ffObject = arrayList.get(0);
    objectId = ffObject.getObjectID();

    return objectId;
}

private void refreshData() {
    ffObjects.clear();
    databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    ArrayList<FFObject> ffobjectsFromDB = databaseHandler.getObjectsList();
    for (int i = 0; i < ffobjectsFromDB.size(); i++) {
        String title = ffobjectsFromDB.get(i).getTitle();
        String dateText = ffobjectsFromDB.get(i).getRecordDate();
        long objectid = ffobjectsFromDB.get(i).getObjectID();

        FFObject ffobject = new FFObject();
        ffobject.setTitle(title);
        ffobject.setRecordDate(dateText);
        ffobject.setObjectID(objectid);
        ffObjects.add(ffobject);
    }
    databaseHandler.close();
    //setup adapter
    ffObjectAdapter = new FFObjectsAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.object_row, ffObjects);
    setListAdapter(ffObjectAdapter);
    ffObjectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class FFObjectsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FFObject>{

    Context context;
    int layoutResource;
    FFObject ffObject;
    ArrayList<FFObject> ffObjectArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public  FFObjectsAdapter (Context con, int resource, ArrayList<FFObject> data){
        super(con,resource,data);
        context = con;
        layoutResource = resource;
        ffObjectArrayList = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ffObjectArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public FFObject getItem(int position) {
        return ffObjectArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition(FFObject item) {
        return super.getPosition(item);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null || row.getTag()==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ffTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.objectName);
            holder.ffDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dateText);

            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.ffObject = getItem(position);
        holder.ffTitle.setText(holder.ffObject.getTitle());
        holder.ffDate.setText(holder.ffObject.getRecordDate());
        holder.ffId = holder.ffObject.getObjectID();

        final  ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;           

        return row;
    }

    class  ViewHolder{
        FFObject ffObject;
        TextView ffTitle;
        long ffId;
        TextView ffDate;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    this.listener= null;
}
}
```

My code for fragment_object_list.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"    android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector">
</ListView>

<TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_objects_in_application" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My code for object_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="12dp">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/objectName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Object title"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateText"
        android:text="date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_below="@id/objectName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"

/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My code for list_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- normal state. -->
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false"  android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_selected" />
    <!-- pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_selected" />
    <!-- selected state. -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false"  android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_selected" />

    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_selected" />
</selector>
```

My code for list_selector_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
            android:endColor="#f7ddb8"
            android:startColor="#f5c98c"
            android:angle="90">
    </gradient>

</shape>
```

I don't use radiobuttons or checkboxes in my list. So I don't think my question is duplicate for stated here [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085177). I successfully use list selector for changing background color of my list rows on click. My question is: how can I set the TOP (first) row of my list to selected state after my list fragment activity started? I want to do it automatically, not on user click event. In the example code here, I use position = 2. I know that's not first row, but at the moment that's not important. Anyway, the code's not working at all. And rows selection goes right only on click event.

Comment: The answer from stated topic is not working for me.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I didn't notice what you're using for your item layout. Apologies.

Comment: I'd love you were right about my question. But I still did not solve it. Maybe I'm setting my adapter wrong? Anyway, I noticed that in onResume method of ListFragment there is still getListView().getChildCount() = 0 and row views are created only after onResume method call. Does it normal?

Comment: I even went in onListItemClick and in the end of method set l.performItemClick(myView,2,2); where myView is row view at position 2. It goes inside onListItemClick, but nothing changes. Background color's still not changes. But when I manually click on listview row - it's color changes immediately. Are list selector useless in this kind of situation?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I've never done this, other than with a `Checkable` item `View`. I just did a few quick tests, and it's not working for me either. I'm not quite sure why that won't select, but I'll let ya know if I ever figure out anything.